# IP Prefix - how do I declare this?

Tags: networking, ip, protocols

Hi I have an IP Prefix issue I would like to declare the following IP's as "safe" using ip prefix "methodology" ("?")

***The IP's first three parts of the IP have been doctored to protect the innocent, but the last digit is correct***

These External IP's are to be considered safe..

`121.241.34.208`
  `121.241.34.209`
  `121.241.34.210`
  `121.241.34.211`

How can I do that? Is 121.241.34.210/1 ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `121.241.34.208/30`, which is equivalent to `121.241.34.208/255.255.255.252`. Bits in the netmask that are `1` mean that the corresponding address bit must match exactly; bits that are `0` mean that anything can match.